# Proper way to handle an empty Stack when implementing a peek() method in Python

Tags: python, data-structures, stack

When implementing a stack using Python, what is the conventional way to handle an operation on an empty stack?

I have the following stack.peek method of a simple stack class implemented using a Python list:

```
def peek(self):
    if not self.empty:
        return self.items[-1]
```

If the stack is empty, is it better to return a None type value or raise an error? I don't like the idea of returning a string stating that "the stack is empty" which is how all of the data structure books I've referenced demonstrate. What is the conventional way to handle this in production code?

Comment: I would go for rising an error, because you should always check `isEmpty()` before you try to take something from the stack (or look at the top element). But in the end it's just a matter of what you prefer in your specific application.

Comment: `collections.deque` raises `IndexError` when trying to `pop` from an empty deque. `list` also raises `IndexError` when trying to `pop` from an empty list. Although in both cases, `pop` can accept an optional index argument, which explains the logic of this exception. `queue.Queue` raises `queue.Empty` when trying to `get` an element from an empty queue.

Comment: `list.pop` raises an IndexError, too. That seems appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Raising an exception is more appropriate than returning anything. Btw, you might consider subclassing `list` to cover the typical `push`, `pop`, and `peek`:

```
class Stack(list):
    push = list.append
    peek = lambda self: self[-1]
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought that would be the most appropriate, but I wasn't quite sure.  I didn't even consider subclassing list; that's nice! thank you for the tip!